# Can a person lose his/her salvation?

Tags: sin, soteriology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a Christian walk away from their salvation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7331/can-a-christian-walk-away-from-their-salvation)

The Bible teaches that when you accept Christ as you personal savior, your name is written in the book of life. Is it written once for ever? According to Bible, can a person lose salvation at any point?

What are the arguments for an against the doctrine of Eternal Security?

Comment: You may want to google "eternal security". This is one of those theological issues which has good Biblical support on both sides, and hence has denominational adherence on both.

Comment: @zefciu They are not duplicates, but closely related. Speaking logically, "walking away" would be a subset of all possible ways to "lose" salvation, even if it is the only member of that set.

Comment: @SanJacinto - it is a completely absurd idea for me to lose one's salvation involuntarily, so for me it is a duplicate. But Ok, I understand your point.

Comment: @zefciu Doctrinally, I agree with you. For the purpose of the site, I think the question is legitimate.

Comment: Just an observation and a suggestion - Christians have been debating this for years, and there are people on both sides of the issue.  It hasn't been answered objectively in centuries, and I don't think it can be here. Both views are based on Scripture and on reason, and which side yu fall on tends to be a matter of how you interpret the same Scriptures.  It's subjective.  A more ***objective*** question would be "What are the arguments for an against the doctrine of Eternal Security?"  Perhaps it could be rephrased?

Comment: @bijoy I think this could only be answered by denomination as they differ.  The bible by itself does not clearly define salvation or how to lose it.  Similarly Hell is really only described in [The Book of Revelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Revelation) else where hell is just a deep pit.

Comment: Similar: [Once saved always saved. Is eternal security Biblical?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/124)

Comment: @DavidStratton: I just modified the question. I am interested to know the teachings of the different denominations, eager to know the different doctrines around this.

Comment: @BijoyThangaraj: The answers in the link David provided give the teachings of different denominations. But that question was closed too.

Comment: @Dan Andrews I don't know the context from which you were talking from but I think there are references in the Bible about one losing salvation. What do you think about Paul saying "...lest I be a cast away"

Comment: @tunmisefashipe Can you add these references as answer?

Comment: @tunmisefashipe It is implied and ambiguous, "...lest I be a cast away" doesn't mean "you'll lose your salvation" to all people.  I encourage you to find references in the bible which specifically talk about salvation and losing it.

Comment: Where does it say your name gets added into the book of life? The Bible only speaks of names being removed, unless you have Scripture that reads otherwise. Thank you in advance